# Key combination (CTRL + F9) causing calling method which should be called only when F9 is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, keydown

I'm working on WPF application, and I'm showing modal/form when Key Combination is pressed, so in my case it is `CTRL + F9`,
so here is my code:

```
//Listening on Window_PreviewKeyDown any key pressing
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 

 if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
 {
    LockAllInputs();
 }

 if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
 {
    e.Handled = true;
 }

 if (e.Key == Key.F11)
 {
     this.Close();
 }
   // Opening modal when Key combination of CTRL AND F9 is pressed
   if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.F9)
   {
     MyModal modal = new MyModal();
    // Do something
   }

   //Hitting a method when only F9 is pressed
    if (e.Key == Key.F9)
    {
      //This is invoked everytime after CTRL+F9
      CallAnotherMethod();
    }
}
```

But the issue in my code is that, when I hit `CTRL+F9` it works fine, but after that method that is invoked when `F9` is pressed is being invoked also..
and that is something I want to avoid, `CTRL+F9` is doing one thing, F9 is doing some another thing, so I dont want `F9` to be invoked when `CTRL+F9` is pressed...

Thanks guys

Comment: Change the second `if` to `else if`.

Comment: Have a squiz at my answer for how to solve your issue @Roxy'Pro .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.F9)
{
  MyModal modal = new MyModal();
  modal.ShowDialog();
  e.Handled = true;//Here I've tried to prevent hitting another method which is being called when F9 is pressed
 }

//Hitting a method when only F9 is pressed
if (e.Key == Key.F9)
{
  //This is invoked everytime after CTRL+F9
  CallAnotherMethod();
}
```

Your code will continue to execute **after** the first `if`, thus will enter the second `if` as well.

The simplest solution would be to change the second `if` to an `else if`:

```
else if (e.Key == Key.F9)
{
  //This is invoked everytime after CTRL+F9
  CallAnotherMethod();
}
```

Another option would be to stop executing the function **inside** the first `if`:

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.F9)
{
  MyModal modal = new MyModal();
  modal.ShowDialog();
  e.Handled = true;
  return;
}
```

Comment: I dont need e.handled there ?

Comment: I am not sure @Roxy'Pro - try removing it and see what happens. _I left the core structure of your code unchanged._

Comment: Both solutions are wrong. They will pass if someone presses Shift + F9 for example... Whatever @Roxy'Pro accepted this as answer so I guess he knows what he has been asking for...

Comment: @IvanIčin I asked you something in a comment below your question, can you please answer me.

Comment: Can you point me to the exact question you are referring to? I appear to have responded to both of them @Roxy'Pro.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be:

```
    //Listening on Window_PreviewKeyDown any key pressing
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 

 if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
 {
    LockAllInputs();
 }

 if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
 {
    e.Handled = true;
 }

 if (e.Key == Key.F11)
 {
     this.Close();
 }
   // Opening modal when Key combination of CTRL AND F9 is pressed
   if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.F9)
   {
     MyModal modal = new MyModal();
     modal.ShowDialog();
     e.Handled = true;//Here I've tried to prevent hitting another method which is being called when F9 is pressed
   }

   //Hitting a method when only F9 is pressed
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None && e.Key == Key.F9)
    {
      CallAnotherMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but I'm wondering why this code is not working when 
 if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None && e.Key == Key.F9)
is moved above first if condition (It looks like it MUST be below.. but why)

Comment: @Roxy'Pro I think you've got something wrong, try it again. It could be as trivial as that you have pressed the wrong key while testing.

Comment: //Please test your code, because when I tested it, after pressing CTRL+F9 first if condition is satisfied and it's running into second one (Keyboard.modifiers none) which is not an option

Comment: @Roxy'Pro this works. You probably use debugger and then drop the ctrl key while using debugger and then the second if can pass. As said this works, whenever you say that this doesn't work try to figure out what mistake you made while testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if the F9 key is the one that triggered the event, you're not checking if any other keys are also pressed. You have 2 solutions:

1. Change the second `if` to an `if else`;
2. Check if the other modifiers are not pressed.